# Variable was declare with a never-completed type

Tags: c, arm, keil

I have three files

- main.c
- myStruct.h
- myStruct.c

I read some post about where to define a structure and encapsulation and I want to declare my structure in the header file and define it in the source file.

This is what I have tested.

myStruct.h

```
// myStruct.h
#include "stdint.h"

typedef struct myStruct myStruct_type;
```

myStruct.c

```
// myStruct.c
#include "myStruct.h"

struct myStruct {
    uint32_t itemA;
    uint32_t itemB;
    uint32_t *pointerA;
    uint32_t *pointerB;
};
```

main.c

```
// main.c
#include "myStruct.h"

myStruct_type testStruct;    // This is where I get the error message

int main (void) {
    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile (Keil uVision) I get the following error "Variable 'testStruct' was declare with a never-completed type myStruct_type testStruct"

What have I missed?

Comment: The struct definition needs to be visible at every point it is required. Move it from c file to h file.

Comment: Move `struct myStruct` into header file. Else it is not visible to main.c

Comment: Alternatively put something like `myStruct_type * new_myStruct_type(void){ return malloc(sizeof (myStruct_type)); }` into `myStruct.c` and in `main()` just define `myStruct_type * pmyStruct = new_myStruct_type();`.

Comment: Also you should use angle brackets for standard includes, in case there happens to be a file of the same name on the local search path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare testStruct like that, `myStruct_type` is an incomplete type. You can at best declare a pointer.

So change

```
myStruct_type testStruct;
```

with

```
myStruct_type *testStruct;
```

You can think of it like, while compiler is compiling `main.c`, it does not have information on members in `myStruct_type`, so it cannot calculate the size of the structure.

Comment: It does mean that you cannot access the members directly, you would have to create functions for that. This is common practice when you want to expose something that must be used to hold state outside your library, without exposing the internal structures. This is mostly suitable for e.g. libraries where you use a private header internally but only define a dummy type in your public header. This way you can build a stable API because you could safely add/remove members between versions without affecting API.
If you're not writing a library, you should not bother.